# how to enable button states android

Tags: android, button

I am working on an application that requires events to be fired off when the **Button** experiences different states like Disabled, Highlighted etc. I need to know if anyone knows how I can define these states on a **Button**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the link provided by "siliconeagle" also check this link....
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

This contains the description about the methods available in Views such as onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) etc.

Comment: I actuallly want to perform something akin to: if(button.setFocussed() == true){.....}, Can this be achieved?

Comment: there is a method "setEnabled(boolean enabled)" which can set the enables state of the view. There is another method "onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)" which will be called on change of focus. You can also find some more methods in the link I provided. I am sorry but I am not able to fully understand your need but I think these will help. Tell me if these helped or you need something else.

Comment: Hey Sumit, my implementation is like this: case HIGLIGHTEDTEXT: if(button.isEnabled()== true{....}, this way if the user selects the HIGHLIGHTEDTEXT option the runtime checks if the button is enabled and implements the necessary code. The thing I am not sure of is the method to use. Can you please help???

Comment: isEnabled method is available in views. Try to use that method if it works. I understand your question but this is the only solution I have right now.

Comment: Thanks Sumit. I will use this and give you feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Anything subclassing View has the states built in, use setEnabled, setFocussed, setSelected, setPressed

if you use a StateList Drawable the drawables will automatically be changed dependingon the state, it goes in something like this (in res/drawable/buttonexample.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/butt_add_on_32" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/butt_add_off_32" />
</selector>
```

then you can add it in you xml layout for the button and it all get managed automatically. see
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: I actuallly want to perform something akin to: if(button.setFocussed() == true){.....}, Can this be achieved?

Comment: use setSelected to hightlight buttons. if you use setEnabled the button wont respon to clicks

Comment: in your drawable xml you then add a state item <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/butt_add_selected_32" />

Answer (score 0):

There are these methods available for Button: isEnabled(), isFocused(), isPressed() and more.

Try taking a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#pubmethods since Button inherits these methods from View.

Comment: I have considered these methods, however it would be really beneficial to me if I could look at an implementation of say, how to determine if a button is highlighted..

Comment: what do you mean? like this: if(myButton.isEnabled()){//do something}